# Customize nodejs redirect message "Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to..."

Tags: node.js, express

I am using nodejs with express.

For some urls I do: `res.redirect(new_url, 302);` and the redirection works fine.

The problem is that the message the server sends is "**Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to http://mysite.com/**" and I'd like to change it to a simple proper html, just like google does. Try to do request to www.google.com (`curl www.google.com`) and you will get:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.il/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

I even can't find where the text is coming from. How can I change it and what is the proper way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remark: for example res.send can have two arguments: "status" and "body" - that's the way I can serve for example 404 with the right status code and custom HTML. But res.redirect unfortunately doesn't have "body" argument.

Answer (score 4):

Use `res.writeHead` with a header then `res.end` with the content (ie. HTML):

```
res.writeHead(302, {'Location': new_url});
res.end('<html>...</html>');
```

Thanks.